# Zoom fails to launch, results in a core dump and memory corruption exit code (134)

Tags: apt, software-installation

In the last week I have had trouble running Zoom on my Ubuntu desktop (v18.04 LTS). It ran with no issues before. I have attempted to uninstall and then reinstall the Zoom package to no avail. When I click on a meeting URL that worked for months I now get a quick flash on the screen of a dialogue box that immediately disappears.

I have done the below to uninstall and reinstall Zoom, with no apparent errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove zoom
$ sudo apt --install ~/Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb
$ touch ~/.config/zoomus.conf
```

The below shows the details of a launch causing a core dump and exit code 134:

```
$ dpkg -l | zoom

ZoomLauncher started.
Zoom not exist at current directory - /home/james
Zoom path is: /opt/zoom
CreateReportChannel bp_server_fd=4
cmd line: 
$HOME = /home/james 
export SSB_HOME=/home/james/.zoom; export QSG_INFO=1; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zoom; export BREAKPAD_CLIENT_FD=3; /opt/zoom/zoom "" 
zoom started.
Client: Breakpad is using Client-Server Mode! client fd = 3
[CZPClientLogMgr::LogClientEnvironment] [MacAddr: 00:E1:18:E0:03:76][client: Linux][OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS][Hardware: CPU Core:6 Frenquency:2.2 G Memory size:15676MB CPU Brand:Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz GPU Brand:][Req ID: ]
Linux Client Version is 3.0.301026.0930
QSG_RENDER_LOOP is 
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = ubuntu:GNOME;   GDMSESSION = ubuntu
Graphics Card Info:: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
Zoom package arch is 64bit, runing OS arch is x86_64
AppIconMgr::systemDesktopName log Desktop Name: ubuntu 
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
qt.scenegraph.general: QSG: basic render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
read pipe thread,open response fifo success!write pipe thread,open request fifo success!Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize 8, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DoubleBuffer), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile)) 
ZoomLauncher: new dump generated from pid 2962, path: /home/james/.zoom/logs/240c4cae-0c2f-489a-190b12a4-bdd29f08.dmp
$HOME = /home/james 
Aborted (core dumped)
success to create child process,status is 34304.
zoom exited normally.
Something went wrong while running zoom,exit code is 134.
ZoomLauncher exit.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by my NVIDIA driver and/or other NVIDIA related libraries being somehow goobered after installing various NVIDIA packages such as CUDA, DeepStream SDK, etc. For example:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

I managed to fix this by updating/upgrading (`sudo apt update/upgrade`) and then rebooting.

Comment: Same - but I had to go into the driver manager to update. I was running nvidia-driver-430, while nvidia-driver-435 was available - updaing and restarting fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the terminal**

Download the DEB installer file from their [Download Center](https://zoom.us/download?os=linux)

Open the Terminal in the download location of your file.

Type in the following command and press Enter to run it.[

```
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

**Dependencies**

If dependencies are not installed, run this command to update the package database, then try installing Zoom again.

```
sudo apt update
```

If you have issues installing, make sure you have the following dependencies installed.

```
libglib2.0-0
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 
libxcb-shape0
libxcb-shm0
libxcb-xfixes0
libxcb-randr0
libxcb-image0
libfontconfig1
libgl1-mesa-glx
libxi6
libsm6
libxrender1
libpulse0
libxcomposite1
libxslt1.1
libsqlite3-0
libxcb-keysyms1
libxcb-xtest0
```

Comment: Please do not send the same answer to different questions. Per policy, we've removed the duplicates and left the first of your answers intact. If the questions all discuss the same thing, then it would be better to flag the questions as duplicates of one of the questions rather than post the same answer numerous times.